# Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor. how can i fix this issue.I want to parse fromJson

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Instance members can't be accessed from a factory constructor. how can i fix this issue

```dart
 factory Bet.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return Bet(
      id=json['id'],
      sport=json['sport'],
      team1=json['team1'],
      team2=json['team2'],
      bet_date=json['bet_date'],
      league=json['league'],
      bet_guess=json['bet_guess'],
      bet_result=json["bet_result"],
      bet_rate=json["bet_rate"],
    );
  }
```

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uvXb.png)

Sorry first time i'm using stackov.
this is the code screen[code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9EFu.png)

Answer (score 7):

if someone else face this issue while calling another function in a factory constructor just make that function static

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the factory keyword.

You can use normal constructor.

```
Bet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    sport = json['sport'];
    team1 = json['team1'];
    team2 = json['team2'];
    bet_date = json['bet_date'];
    league = json['league'];
    bet_guess = json['bet_guess'];
    bet_result = json["bet_result"];
    bet_rate = json["bet_rate"];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer here works, but if you still want to use a factory constructor you need to properly use named parameters, which are assigned with a colon, not an equals.

```dart
factory Bet.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return Bet(
      id: json['id'],
      sport: json['sport'],
      team1: json['team1'],
      team2: json['team2'],
      bet_date: json['bet_date'],
      league: json['league'],
      bet_guess: json['bet_guess'],
      bet_result: json["bet_result"],
      bet_rate: json["bet_rate"],
    );
  }
```